# Renaming Files with Bad Characters

Tags: regex, powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but when I try to `Rename-Item` with a new filename I keep running into an error saying the original file that I want to rename does not exist. My goal is to remove multiple "bad" characters from the given file name. Bad characters are `[]<>:*` and I'm only currently looking at `[]` to make sure it works before adding the rest.

**Code Example:**

```cs
$Directory  = "G:\TEMP\2016\"
$ExcelFiles = Get-ChildItem $Directory -Recurse -Include *.xls,*.xlsx |
              % {$_.FullName}

foreach ($excelfile in $excelfiles) {
    #Write-Host "Checking $excelfile"

    if ($excelfile -match "\[|\]") {
        $newfilename = $excelfile -replace "[\[\]]", ""
        Rename-Item $excelfile -NewName $newfilename
    }
}
```

Comment: `Rename-Item -LiteralPath $excelfile ...`

Comment: You are a God, that was it, thank you. Please post as an answer for credit.